# How to get MVC ActionLink Full Path in Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to set the class on the selected menu anchor based on the URL. I have below actionlinks

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home","Index","Home" new {type="new task"},null)
@Html.ActionLink("Home","Index")
```

I need to get its fullpath in Jquery to change the selected link based on the url as given below

```
$("a").each(function () {
 if (location.indexOf($(this).prop('href')) != -1) {
                          $(this).addClass('mlnkactive').siblings().removeClass('mlnkactive');
                        $(this).parent().addClass('mlnkactive').siblings().removeClass('mlnkactive');
});
```

The problem is that when i get href of the links using $(this).prop('href') , both of the above Home links have the same href.So both of the Anchors are selected and I am unable to set the class on the selected Link based on URL.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you add a css class to the selected link server side (in the ActionLink)?

```
<div id="menulinks">
    @Html.ActionLink("Home","Index","Home" new {type="new task"}, new { @class = "mlnkactive" })
    @Html.ActionLink("Home","Index")
</div>
```

And then remove the class and add it to the new selected link client side? Like this:

```
$('#menulinks a').click(function(){
    $('#menulinks a').removeClass('mlnkactive');
    $(this).addClass('mlnkactive');
}
```

Comment: i want a generic solution.  i have like 14 menu items..4 menu items point to the same page with different querystring..the problem is that in jquery href attribute returns the same string '/Home/' and skips the querystring part..all the anchors with the same path gets selected.i dont want to hardcode and check each anchor against the querystring or something. There should be some way to deal with it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to user normal  with @Url.Action inside href attribute. For example:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("action_name", "controller", new { action_parametr_name = action_parameter_value})">Link 1</a>
```